# ion-toggle button's ionChange event call function infinitely

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4

Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot my issue?
 I am calling function on ionchange of ion-toggle, function called infinitely i dont know why.

                            
                                {{n.ContentTitle }}
                                
                            
                        
updatePreferences(){

```
var token="Bearer "+this._auth.auth.token;
this._ajax.savePreferences(this._auth.auth.membershipId,token,this.notificationPref)
.subscribe(response=>{

    this._preference.getPreferences("Updating Settings...");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._ngZone.run(()=>{
        this.notificationPref=this._preference.preferences.settings;
      });

      }, 1000);
      //console.log("Notification Prefrence settings");
    // this._FCM.trackEvent("Notification Prefrence settings","toggel","Notification pref "+notification_title +" is "+value,1);
},
error=>{
    this._popup.presentAlert("Please verify you are connected to the internet.","Update operation failed.");
});
```

} (edited)

Answer (score 0):

it goes into infinite loop because i was calling ajax call inside ajax.